# limiting the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value

Tags: mysql, select, sum

i m trying to limit the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value but i m getting unexpected results.

```
CREATE TABLE buy (
  id int not null,
  volume decimal(9,4) not null,
  price decimal(9,2) not null
 );

insert buy (id, volume, price) values 
(1, 1.0000, 14250.00),
(2, 0.2500, 14251.10),
(3, 0.2500, 14250.00),
(4, 0.0050, 14200.00),
(5, 0.5000, 14255.01);
```

expected result selected ids 5,2,1(because ordering by higest price) but it selects ids 2,1,3

```
SELECT t.id, t.volume, t.price,
(SELECT SUM(volume) FROM buy WHERE id <= t.id) 'RequiredVolume'
FROM buy t
HAVING RequiredVolume <= '1.5000'
ORDER BY price DESC, id ASC;

| id | volume |   price | RequiredVolume |
|----|--------|---------|----------------|
|  2 |   0.25 | 14251.1 |           1.25 |
|  1 |      1 |   14250 |              1 |
|  3 |   0.25 |   14250 |            1.5 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef024/3/0

Comment: I'm unsure as to why you expect 5,2,1 and not 4 and three. It's also not clear what you are trying to sum. Right now you sum the volumes of everything below the current ID so 5 and 4 have a requiredvolume of over 1.5 so it's clear those records won't be returned. Also you probably shouldn't compare requiredvolume to a string literal.

Comment: Can you tell me how this is different to the other question that I answered for you [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187970/selecting-multiple-rows-by-given-amount-of-volume/187987#187987)?

Comment: i really didn't see your answer. it's perfect works thank u

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be due to the nested query being `>=` and not `=`.

This gives the output you described:

```
SELECT t.id, t.volume, t.price,
(SELECT SUM(volume) FROM buy WHERE id = t.id) 'RequiredVolume'
FROM buy t
HAVING RequiredVolume <= '1.5000'
ORDER BY price DESC, id ASC;
```

Memo - Can you please post what your expected results would be for all fields and not just the ID ordering.

Comment: No it doesn't, it returns all rows, not just 5,2,1

Comment: Because all the rows meet the filtering criteria of being less than the required volume of 1.5?

Comment: OP states "expected result selected ids 5,2,1". Not sure why he expects them though, I asked for clarification on the question

Comment: Thank you. The expected `RequiredVolume` for ID 5 would be 2.005 if the current `<=` logic is correct. Which in turn wouldn't meet the criteria for `<= 1.5`

Comment: what about using <> and why id 4 selected? HAVING RequiredVolume <> 1.5000

Comment: @memo Still not sure what you're aiming for. `requiredvolume <> 1.5000´ would return everything except number 3 obviously

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MySQL guy, but maybe this works for you though it will only return records 5 and 2 because records 5, 2, and 1 have a rolling sum of 1.75 instead of the 1.5 you're filtering for.

```
SELECT t.id, t.volume, t.price,
(SELECT SUM(volume) FROM buy WHERE (id <> t.id AND price > t.price) OR (id < t.id AND price = t.price) OR (id = t.id)) 'RequiredVolume'
FROM buy t
HAVING RequiredVolume <= 1.5
ORDER BY price DESC, id ASC;
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef024/38) with the `HAVING` clause *commented out* to show this would only return records 5 and 2 in the event this logic is indeed what you're after.